# Count characters in specific line

Tags: java, count

I am reading a file and check the number of lines, characters and the longest line and I want to know the number of characters in the second line of the file. How can I do it?

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:/.../mrr569.fasta"));
    int lines = 0;
    int characters = 0;
    int maxCharacters = 0;
    String longestLine = "";

    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        lines++;
        characters += line.length();

        if (maxCharacters < line.length()) {
            maxCharacters = line.length();
            longestLine = line;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(lines);
    System.out.println(characters);
    System.out.println(longestLine);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of the line you are on. So create a variable `lineNo`.

```
int lineNo=1;
```

You also need to store the number of characters in the second line:

```
int charsInSecondLine=0;
```

and at the end of the while loop increment this variable:

```
lineNo++;
```

Then in the while loop (before the increment) add an if statement that checks if it is the second line

```
if(lineNo==2){
    charsInSecondLine=line.length();
}
```

So the code becomes:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:/.../mrr569.fasta"));
int lines = 0;
int characters = 0;
int maxCharacters = 0;
int lineNo = 1;
int charsInSecondLine = 0;
String longestLine = "";

while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = input.nextLine();
    lines++;
    characters += line.length();

    if (maxCharacters < line.length()) {
        maxCharacters = line.length();
        longestLine = line;
    }

    if(lineNo==2){
        charsInSecondLine=line.length();
    }
    lineNo++;
}
System.out.println(lines);
System.out.println(characters);
System.out.println(longestLine);
System.out.println(charsInSecondLine);
```

Answer (score -1):

Add some condition into the loop. For example

```
if(line.startsWith(">")) {
   continue;
}
```

Or add line counter and base your condition on it.

Comment: should i put that before the while-loop or after the while loop? and how i count just one Line and not the chars of all lines . i want to count the chars of the second line and not all chars of all lines